# Webpack Can't resolve other modules while building in my boilerplate project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I've created boilder plate project with webpack, react, typescript etc. but whenever I build my project, webpack throw this errors on my entry point that Cannot resolve other modules (which is just simple Login component)
This is my webpack's error message

```
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/Login' in '/Users/myname/Desktop/Projects/front/src'
 @ ./src/index.tsx 6:14-43
```

This is my index.tsx file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';


ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Login />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And this is my Login components, which webpack cannot resolve

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default () => <div>Login</div>;
```

This is my webpack config and package.json's scripts

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        options: {
          useCache: true,
          reportFiles: ['src/**/*.{ts,tsx}']
        }
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'template/index.html'
    })
  ],
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/'),
    filename: 'bundle.[hash].js'
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

package.json's scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
```

I tried minimize my project as possible so you can focus on this single problem, why the hack my webpack cannot resolve ordinary component file? you can find this minimized project on https://github.com/sh2045/myproblem
you can just clone it, and run

```
npm i 
npm run build
```

and you can see error message, please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `awesome-typescript-loader` why don't you try the loader's recommended by [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) for typescript

**To fix your problem,**

Install this `node` package `npm install --save-dev typescript ts-loader`. This is the loader that does ts to js conversion.

You need to remove `awesome-typescript-loader` and use `ts-loader` in `webpack.config.js`. Below is the updated `webpack.config.js`. You can use this configuration and execute `npm run build` and verify if your `webpack` bundles the project without errors

**Modified webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'template/index.html'
    })
  ],
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/'),
    filename: 'bundle.[hash].js'
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

**Note** When i downloaded & setup your project from your git, this package `npm i acorn --save` was missing in your `package.json` i believe. so i had to install it manually

Comment: problem wasn't the loader, it was my resolve.extensions(i had to add tsx, ts for that). thanks for the answer though